# cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, char, строки

Ошибка возникает в Arduino IDE
Переменная Задается так (код в text помещается так, находится внутри функции):

```
String text = bot.messages[i].text;
```

Ошибка возникает здесь

```
else if (isspace(text[2]) == true || isspace(text[1]) == true){
    for (int numb = 0; numb < strlen(text); numb++){
      if (isdigit(text[numb] == true && tempvvod < 2) == true){
        tempvvod1 += text[numb];
        tempvvod += 1;
      }
      else if (isdigit(text[numb] == true && tempvvod > 1))
      tempvvod2 += text[numb];
      tempvvod +=1;
    }
```

Выглядит так:
exit status 1
cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*'

Нужно было из строки "13 14" забрать цифры, (может выглядеть как "1 2", "12 1", "1 12"), сохранить их в переменных. На Python проблем в реализации не возникло, а вот в C++ возникли.

upd:

```
bool tempvvodstate = true;
String tempvvod1 = ""; 
String tempvvod2 = ""; 
int tempvvod = 0;
```

Comment: Приведите более полный код. Покажите объявление переменных `tempvvod tempvvod1 tempvvod2 text[]`. И код, который помещает строку в `text[]`.

Comment: Немного дополнил. 
>И код, который помещает строку в `text[]`
это показал,  `String text = bot.messages[i].text;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас ошибка в `strlen(text)`. Вы пытаетесь проверить длину строки `std::string` функцией, принимающей нуль-терминированные `c`-строки.
Либо делаете так

```
for (int numb = 0; numb < strlen(text.c_str()); numb++)
```

Но правильнее

```
for (int numb = 0; numb < text.size(); numb++)
// или
for (int numb = 0; numb < text.length(); numb++)
```

Comment: вы с библиотекой попутали чуток. в вопросе не std.

Comment: Спасибо, 3 вариант помог.